# JS retrieve deep field while ignoring missing along the way fields

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing

Is there a simple way or popular NodeJS library that allows retrieving a deep field in a JSON object in Javascript without having to check for null at each level? For instance, when trying to parse this object:

```
var o = {"a": {"b": {"c": {"d": 1}}}}
```

If I wanted the value for `d`, I'd have to do something like

```
if (o && o['a'] && o['a']['b'] && o['a']['b']['c']) { ... }
```

It's trivial to write, but I'm wondering what's the most popular way to do this? I could imagine something like:

```
var value = deepGet(o, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']);
```

Note: I'm not looking for the code to do this. Like I said, it's trivial to implement. I'm interested in what's the most common way to do this. There must be some nice pattern that doesn't require writing a function, or there's a pre-existing function that can be used.

Comment: What do you want to get if any of the levels dont exist?

Comment: Just undefined if any of the levels are empty.

Comment: may be give a look to this:http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

```
function deepGet (obj, key_array) {
    for (var i = 0; obj && i < key_array.length; obj = obj[key_array[i++]]) ;
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
function deepGet(obj, path) {
  var segment = path[0];
  if(path.length === 1) {
     return obj[path[0]];
   }
   else if(obj[segment]) {
     return deepGet(obj[segment], path.slice(1));
   }
   else {
    return undefined;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var o = {"a": {"b": {"c": {"d": 1}}}};
var value = deepGet(o, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']);

function deepGet(obj, pathArr){
    var curr = obj;

    for(var i = 0 ; i < pathArr.length && curr ;i++)
    {
        curr = curr[pathArr[i]];
    }

    return curr;
}

console.log(value); // 1
```

[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/jz3vmqwr/).